# How to set binary mode by default when FTPing to a remote site?

Tags: ftp

I typically use the bash command line when I need to FTP something. I have found that certain FTP servers are not set to binary mode by default and unless I remember to do so, the file sent will be corrupt. Is there a way to set binary mode automatically every time I access a remote ftp server?

Comment: Why not issue 'bin' each time you do an upload?

Comment: Very good question! I have just strace'ed the ftp command. I see that ftp reads .netrc, but unfortunately netrc supports only username/passwd AFAIK.

Comment: Steven - if someone answers this question with an expect script, would you then have to migrate that answer back to SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use ftp, then you can put arbitary commands into the netrc by defining a macro. If the macro is called init, then it will be automatically executed, like this

```
machine server
login user
password password
macdef init
binary
```

Any commands between the macdef line and the blank line will be executed as soon as the login is complete.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I simply created .netrc and added binary, tested, and it works as you said. However, I am really liking ncftp now, which will be my new ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

Use ncftp, which defaults to binary.

Comment: Thanks for the ncftp tip. I love the bookmark feature as well.